# Where should the data update date be entered into the FGDC metadata form (esri)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, metadata

if you've edited data recently (a gdb feature class), either spatial or tabular, and you want to capture the "update date" and possibly a note about what was updated, without overwriting the "publication date" or "edition" feilds in the metadata, where should it go?  Perhaps i'm interpreting the meaning of the publication/edition dates incorrectly and that's what they're for...? any known/definitive answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Time period of content:
(Multiple Dates and Times)

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Using_the_FGDC_metadata_editor_to_document_your_data

Comment: fixed in ArcGIS10 SP1 PDF http://downloads2.esri.com/support/documentation/ao_/10.0_SP1_Announcement.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "Nowhere". ESRI automagically adds a last updated date/timestamp to the metadata for you. To prove this to yourself: Look at your metadata in the FGDC ESRI stylesheet, the last entry on the Description tab is called "Details about this document". Click on that entry to spill it open and see the "Contents last updated date/timestamps".

Comment: Brian thanks for the response, however the question relates to the date that the DATA was last updated, not the METADATA document.  I believe Mapperz answer is correct.  I was ultimately looking for an "automagical" answer so it's unfortunate that the software does auto-populate the date modified date of the data into the metadata documents. that would be ideal.